# Im new in pyomo, and im having trouble on declarating data to the sets and params. I always get the message of syntaxerror

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, set, pyomo

Im not sure if the problem relies on the versions im using or if im not importing something, but the sources from where i got this example didnt mention any other environment rather than that of pyomo.environ (im working on python 3.6). I downloaded coopr because i thought it was important but there were no changes. I already try to make a .dat file but when i run the solver i get the same error message. any suggestions? Im reading the book of pyomo (2012) and this is the easiest way to declare data so i would like to learn it. Also if you know about a pyomo course (formal or informal), please share. Thanks a lot for your time.

```
from pyomo.environ import*
from coopr.pyomo import*

model = AbstractModel()
# nodes in the networks
model.N = Set()
#network arcs
model.A = Set(within=model.N*model.N) #within=set used for validation, it is a sueprset off the set being declared

# model parameters

#source node
model.s = Param(within=model.N)
#sink node
model.t = Param(within=model.N)
#flow capacity limits
model.c = Param(model.A)

#the flow over each arc
model.f = Var(model.A, within=NonNegativeReals)

# Maximize the flow into the sink nodes
def total_rule(model):
    return sum(model.f[i,j] for (i,j) in model.A if j== value(model.t))
model.total = Objective(rule=total_rule, sense=maximize)

# Enforce an upper limit on the flow across each arc
def limit_rule(model, i, j):
    return model.f[i,j] <= model.c[i,j]
model.limit = Constraint(model.A, rule=limit_rule)

# Enforce flow through each node
def flow_rule(model, k):
    if k == value(model.s) or k == value(model.t):
        return Constraint.Skip
    inFlow = sum(model.f[i,j] for (i,j) in model.A if j==k)
    outFlow = sum(model.f[i,j] for (i,j) in model.A if i==k)
    return inFlow == outflow
model.flow = Constraint(model.N, rule=flow_rule)

set N := Zoo A B C D E Home;                                   <-----

  File "<ipython-input-6-1d6651500789>", line 1                <-----
    set: N := Zoo A B C D E Home;                              <------
           ^                                                   <------
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                    <------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with concrete models... just because it relieves you of working with separate data files and Python is super easy to make your sets and data within the framework of the model.  You can start your model like:

```
from pyomo.environ import*
#from coopr.pyomo import*

model = ConcreteModel()   # AbstractModel()
# nodes in the networks
nodes = {'Zoo', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Home'}
model.N = Set(initialize=nodes)
```

If you go the abstract route, it appears above you have your set definition inside the python file??  That data needs to be in a separate file.

https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_overview/simple_examples.html#a-simple-concrete-pyomo-model

Comment: alright, then, thanks for the advice, i will start with concrete models. And yes, i was trying to put the data inside the python file. thank you for letting me know that mistake, i wasnt able to see it...

Comment: Yeah, some of the dox aren't real clear on that for abstract models.  If you do them, model in one file, data in another, run it from the command line.  Concrete are a bit easier because they are "all in one" and the .py file can run it all and show results.  Maybe not as flexible as Abstract, but easier to get going on.  In fact, for a couple of large models I've worked on, I do it all in concrete, because it is easier to do set manipulations and debugging.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers, with them, i managed to solve this one (after 3 days trying), will take your advice about concret to get some practice and then come back to abstract. all the best